# Set URL to the cancelled path when redirecting to the 404 page from a resolver

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let's say we have the following route configuration:

```
[{
    path: "people",
    children: [
        {
            path: ":id",
            component: PersonProfileComponent,
            resolve: { person: PersonResolver },
            children: [
                { path: "", component: PersonOverviewComponent },
                { path: "photos", component: PersonPhotoListComponent }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ path: "404", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
{ path: "**",  component: PageNotFoundComponent }]
```

I want to redirect to the 404 page when user try to navigate to any of these:

```
/people/{non-existing-id}
/people/{non-existing-id}/photos
/people/{existing-id}/{non-existing-subpage}
```

The third case is handled by the ** route since it's not matched by any of the previous routes. So the `PersonResolver` has to handle the first two cases.

```
export class PersonResolver implements Resolve<Person> {
    constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService, private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Person> {
        return this.peopleService.find(id).catch(error => {
            if (error instanceof Response) {
                if (error.status === 404) {
                    this.router.navigate(["/404"]);
                }
                else {
                    //todo
                }
            }
            else {
                //todo
            }
            return Observable.of(null);
        });
    }
}
```

Everything works but the problem is that when the 404 page is shown the browser URL is updated to `<hostname>/404` (as expected). My question is **how to set the URL to the path we've just cancelled** (eg. `<hostname>/people/fake-id/photos`) as this is how 404 is handled all over the web. (I also tried passing `{skipLocationChange: true}` to `router.navigate()` but this keeps the location before that we are trying to navigate to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its possible to change url without navigating using `Location` - [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html)

You can react on error with subscribing to `Router.events - NavigationError` and then show 404 with `skipLocationChange` and then change location with `location.go`

You have to change url after navigation to 404 is complete.

```
  constructor(router: Router, location: Location) {
    router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationError)
      .subscribe((event: NavigationError) => {
        router.navigate(["/404"], {skipLocationChange: true})
          .then(() =>  location.go(event.url));
      })
  }
```

I would prefer doing this in my routing module, but it could be done also in resolver.

`Router.events` are not very well documented yet, you can check at least list of them [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Event-type-alias.html) and do some logging.

Answer (score 2):

@Víťa Plšek was really good for inspiration, but it did not work for me.

Here's how I did:

```
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    // Do some stuff that fails...
    // Redirect to 404.
    return this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .first()
      .subscribe((event: NavigationError) => (
        this.router.navigate(['/404'], {skipLocationChange: true})
        .then(() =>  this.location.go(event.url))
      ));
  }
```

---

### Cleaner version:

my-component-resolver.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class YoutubeVideoResolver {

  constructor(
    private resolverNavigation: ResolverNavigation,
    private router: Router,
    private http: Http,
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    this.http.get('/foo')
      .map((response) => {
        // Found. Do something with the data.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Not found. Redirect to 404.
        this.resolverNavigation.to404();
        return Observable.of(null);
      });
  }
}
```

resolver-navigation.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {
  Router,
  NavigationEnd,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ResolverNavigation {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
  ) {}

  to404(): void {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .first()
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => (
        this.router.navigate(['/404'], {skipLocationChange: true})
          .then(() =>  this.location.go(event.url))
      ));
  }
}
```